# How to check if object in for loop exists in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop that is working, but i want to make sure my code is ready for server side problems as well. Is there something i can use to test before putting everything running?

my for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.sources.length; i++) {
  selectBoxSource += '<option value="' + data.sources[i].id + '">' + 
    domainid[i].source + '</option>';
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by server side problems? What are you doing with this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript you can check existence of any object just by calling a condition with it

```
if (data.sources[i]) {
  // Do whatever you want here, even call data.sources[i].id
}
```

So for you code if you want to check existence of those objects it would become like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.sources.length; i++) {
  if (data.sources[i] && domainid[i]) {
    selectBoxSource += '<option value="' + data.sources[i].id + '">' + 
      domainid[i].source + '</option>';
  }
}
```

A higher level of validation would be

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.sources.length; i++) {
  if (data.sources[i] && data.sources[i].id && domainid[i] && domainid[i].source) {
    selectBoxSource += '<option value="' + data.sources[i].id + '">' + 
      domainid[i].source + '</option>';
  }
}
```